# Retaining and incrementing __COUNTER__ value across a complete make session?

Tags: c++, macros

I have an embedded programming language that has syntax similar to C language. It also supports the macro `__COUNTER__`. I require a particular function to have an incremented argument every time I call it. And this function could be called across multiple files in the project and the values need to be incremented across files. I don't want to manually track the values across files (Or use a common header). I want to use the Counter macro to auto update this argument. My problem is that the macro resets in a new file. Is there any way I can achieve this by

1. Retaining and incrementing the macro value across the build session?
2. Or some other entirely new way to do this?

Comment: Macros are resolved at compile-time (or just before depending on your viewpoint) whereas function calls occur at run-time. Do you mean each time a call to the function occurs in the source code?

Comment: Do you need continuous values or unique would be sufficient?

Comment: @vlp Continuous is needed since they correspond to channels in the system.

Comment: @NeilKirk Yes. Every time the function call occurs in the source code. I want the preprocessor to take care of the numerical argument.

Comment: Could be done with a custom preprocessing script a la `perl -i -pe 's/\b__COUNTER__\b/$c++/eg' *.cpp`.

Comment: One silly solution would be to `#include` all your code (.c) in a single file...then compile this single file...probably not what you are looking for :/ And probably a very bad idea if you use `static`.

Comment: @melpomene I didn't want to add another language into this. :/

Comment: @vlp Wait. That's actually not silly. How do I do this in the makefile itself? Any way to do this? As long as I can automate this I think it should be okay.

Comment: @SPRajagopal `cat *.inc > onebigfile.cpp` or something along those lines.

Comment: @melpomene This is a project with subdirectories and separate set of dependencies for each. I am not sure if this will work.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by dependencies but in principle arbitrary subdirectories could be handled with `find . -name '*.inc' -exec cat {} + > onebigfile.cpp`.

Comment: The thing would break at the first `static` function name collision.

Comment: @melpomene there are multiple modules in it. And these modules are organized in folders. And I can write code that uses some of these folders. I guess emulate this by making a complete bash script.

Comment: I am afraid that if your code is complex, then using this way is a very bad idea. Custom preprocessor script is much better.

Comment: @vlp how would I do that?

Comment: Why do you need the precompiler to take care of this? Can't you just use a global variable plus a static in each function to make sure the first is incremented only once per function?

Comment: @MatteoItalia could you tell me in detail? Not sure I understand.

Comment: Does the solution need to work with incremental and/or parallel builds? Since both of these pretty much forbid any preprocessor-based solution.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't need to be evaluated at compile time, but runtime suffices, you could do something like:

```
// in a .cpp
int global_counter;
```

And in each relevant function:

```
extern int global_counter;
const static int counter=global_counter++;
// now in counter you have your value
```

`counter` gets assigned a unique, monotonically increasing, per-function global id (even though this happens at runtime, and the exact value depends on the order of call of the functions). Also notice that, if your program is multithreaded, you'll want to use an `std::atomic_int`.

Comment: Ah. This could work if it's not an embedded project. Unfortunately I cannot share variables across physical cores. Architecture issues.

Comment: Ouch yet another bizarre DSP, huh? Anyhow, given that you work on a peculiar platform, you should explain it in detail in your question (processor, toolchain, limitations in respect to "regular" C or C++, etc.), otherwise it's going to be tough to receive meaningful answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you like silly solutions -- here we go. Pretty please do have a confirmed backup of your sources (i.e. test this code on a copy).

To substitute all occurrences of `__COUNTER__` with incrementing value, keeping original files in `.orig` (thanks to @melpomene, I am not into perl):

```
perl -i.orig -p -e '$a='\''/*GENERATED*/'\''; s/\b__COUNTER__\b/$c++.$a/eg'
```

To find out the largest value used in substitution (shell):

```
grep -ho '[1234567890]*/\*GENERATED\*/' *.cpp | cut -d/ -f 1 | sort -n | tail -n 1
```

---

Combined solution (shell script):

```
# Find out the largest value used
MAXUSED=$(grep -ho '[1234567890]*/\*GENERATED\*/' *.cpp | cut -d/ -f 1 | sort | tail -n 1)
# Substitute, starting from MAXUSED+1
perl -i.orig -p -e '$m='"$MAXUSED"'+1; $a='\''/*GENERATED*/'\''; s/\b__COUNTER__\b/(($c++)+$m).$a/eg' *.cpp
```

Good luck!

Comment: I don't like solutions that can make devastating changes to my HDD.  Please reconsider the posting of this...

Comment: I do not like solutions which do not warn that they were hacked together in 10 mins. And I don't like downvoters who do not understand this. And I am here to learn and help.

Comment: We are all here to help.  But, posting a solution that requires the kind of disclaimer you are using... imagine him naively running this at his desk job on a group project because he didn't understand the ramification like he thought he did.  Just saying that options that can possibly go nuclear are not the best things to post.

Comment: As I am quite new here (2 months) what I should I do then -- I did my best with the disclaimer...This solution should work.

Comment: First of all suggest that he back up all files, then place only the files he wants to modify in one location, then make sure the script only works on that one location.  But better would be to change your scripts to output new files in new locations instead of overwriting old (if I am understanding your code - I am not a perl expert.) so that nothing could be lost on a typo.

Comment: But honestly, your disclaimer reads like drug ads on TV where the side effects include loss of vision, uncontrollable bleeding, frothing at the mouth, and death. :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan What do you think now? And one big thank you that you responded to my messages...

Comment: If your scripts are making backup copies of originals or outputting to new locations, state it.  Also, add more information on exactly what you are doing above - what you mean by replace `__COUNTER__` with value with backup.  That doesn't read correctly in English and if something is modifying source files, I want to know and know why.  Basically, just flesh the answer out further and I'll swap my vote.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Better now? And I hope we both know that it is not about your vote :) Thank you again.